# Proxy Pass via ajp does not work for hashed url

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, jboss

I have apache in front of Jboss working on 80 port and jboss listens to 8080. Apache forwards every request to Jboss. So its quiet standard scenario nothing fancy . . .

My first task was to log real ip in jboss log. (Coz I have proxy inside apache server and rewrite Engine.)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test.com
  ServerAlias test.com
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access.log combined

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteLogLevel 5
  RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/rewrite.log"
  RewriteRule   ^/test.txt$ /someurl/search.cgi?iHash=somehash [P]
  RewriteRule   ^/test2$ /just/static/url/ [P]
  ProxyRequests off
  <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
 </Proxy>
       ProxyPass / http://test.com:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://test.com:8080/
```

So I solved this problem with ajp:

```
<Location /test2>
 ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/just/static/url/
 ProxyPassReverse ajp://localhost:8009/just/static/url/
</Location>
```

But now the problem Is, that it only works for static url not with hashed url. The problem is that apache kinda redirects url, but i get HTTP Status 404 error from Jboss. Maybe someone had the same problem or know the solution.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_jk with ajp.

First configure Jboss to work with mod_jk, for example: [jboss+jk](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/clustering-http-jboss.html)

I supose I guess connector port settings to 8009. You can configure your apache with mod_jk and ajp for redirection. And mount your url with:

```
<IfModule mod_jk.c>
 # a list of Server instances
 JkWorkerProperty worker.list=JBossA
 # connection properties to instance A on localhost
 JkWorkerProperty worker.tomcatA.type=ajp13
 JkWorkerProperty worker.tomcatA.host=localhost
 JkWorkerProperty worker.tomcatA.port=8009
 # some other configuration
 JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
 # forwarding URL prefixes to Server instances
 JkMount /APPUrl/* JbossA
</IfModule>
```

and workers.properties with:

```
worker.list=jk-status
worker.jk-status.type=status
worker.jk-status.read_only=true
worker.list=jk-manager
worker.jk-manager.type=status
worker.list=jk-status
worker.jk-status.type=status
worker.jk-status.read_only=true
worker.list=jk-manager
worker.jk-manager.type=status
worker.balancer.error_escalation_time=0
worker.balancer.max_reply_timeouts=10
worker.balancer.balance_workers=node1
worker.node1.reference=worker.template
worker.node1.host=localhost
worker.node1.port=8109
worker.node1.activation=A
worker.balancer.balance_workers=node2
worker.node2.reference=worker.template
worker.node2.host=localhost
worker.node2.port=8209
worker.node2.activation=A
worker.template.type=ajp13
worker.template.socket_connect_timeout=5000
worker.template.socket_keepalive=true
worker.template.ping_mode=A
worker.template.ping_timeout=10000
worker.template.connection_pool_minsize=0
worker.template.connection_pool_timeout=600
worker.template.reply_timeout=300000
worker.template.recovery_options=3
worker.list=ajp13
worker.ajp13.port=8009
worker.ajp13.host=localhost
worker.ajp13.type=ajp13
worker.ajp13.lbfactor=1
```